# Can Windows 10 be used for commercial purposes?

Tags: is-x-legal, turkey

I have an activated copy of  **Windows 10 Home**. I am from Turkey and I work as freelancer at my home (developing and selling web templates).

Is using it for commercial purposes like this legal?

Comment: This is asking the legal effect of a widely distributed, well-known license. It is not asking for specific legal advice, and should not be closed as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, you may

The [Microsoft license](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm) contains a number of restrictions in section 2 c (Restrictions)  In particular 2 c (v) says that yu may not:

> use the software as server software, for commercial hosting, make the software available for simultaneous use by multiple users over a network, install the software on a server and allow users to access it remotely, or install the software on a device for use only by remote users;

It does not restri8ct use in a business or professional way.

If it did, that might be arguable as to whether it would be legal in the US -- I don't know about Turkish law on such a point. But there is no such restriction, so there is no issue for you on that point.